# ATMega32, Using PORTA as digital io has digital "crosstalk"

Tags: noise, button, crosstalk

I have multiple switches connected to portA on an atmega32. They are set as an input with internal pullups. There are no external pullups. The switches ground out the pins. I'm not debouncing the switches because their state is latched in software.

My problem is that when button 0, connected to pin0 on porta, is pressed for ~30ms, a 0.4ms pulse appears on the adjacent pins. Like a type of 'digital crosstalk'.

So now I'm forced to debounce to prevent registering and latching false button presses. I attached a logic analyzer to the pins. Here is the screenshot. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZris.png Channel 5 is connected to the button that I pressed multiple times. You can see the spikes on the adjacent channel.

Any idea what might be happening. Could this have something to do with the port also being part of the ADC module, or possibly the fact that I'm using an older chip?

I have AVcc connected to vcc with 10uF to ground. Aref is internally set to vcc and has an external 3.3uF capacitor.

Comment: What voltages are you using for Vcc and AVcc?  What are the impedances of your power supplies?  Can you put an oscilloscope on the pin connected to the button you're pressing? (and also on Vcc and AVcc?)  Could it be your power supply drooping?  Looking at the datasheet this seems possible (although quite unlikely), the device should reset at 0.2Vcc but logic low input is at 0.3Vcc.  Might be worth checking anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like capacitive crosstalk.  The internal pullups are not particularly strong so if the traces are next to each other it's possible for the changing voltage in one wire to couple to an adjacent wire.  I would suggest adding capacitors from the IO pins to ground near the microcontroller to help hold the state on the pins.  Probably standard 0.1 uF caps should be sufficient.  You could also try stronger external pullups.  If 10k doesn't work, then try 4.7k or 1k.

Comment: I think a small RC filter on a pushbutton is always a good idea. You can use it to debounce and it will also reject these spikes.